# Django: Does unique_together imply db_index=True in the same way that ForeignKey does?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-indexes

A field on a model, `foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)` will automatically add a database index for the column, in order to make look-ups faster. That's good and well, but Django's docs don't state whether the fields in a model-meta's `unique_together` receive the same treatment. I happen to have a model in which one char field which is listed in `unique_together` requires an index for quick lookups. I know that it won't hurt anything to add a duplicate `db_index=True` in the field definition, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unique_together` does not automatically add indexes for each field included in the list.

The new versions of Django suggest using Index & constraint meta options instead:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#index-together

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/indexes/

And an example model from an open source project:

class GroupResult(models.Model):
"""Task Group result/status."""

```
group_id = models.CharField(
    max_length=getattr(
        settings,
        "DJANGO_CELERY_RESULTS_TASK_ID_MAX_LENGTH",
        255
    ),
    unique=True,
    verbose_name=_("Group ID"),
    help_text=_("Celery ID for the Group that was run"),
)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True,
    verbose_name=_("Created DateTime"),
    help_text=_("Datetime field when the group result was created in UTC"),
)
date_done = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now=True,
    verbose_name=_("Completed DateTime"),
    help_text=_("Datetime field when the group was completed in UTC"),
)
content_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=128,
    verbose_name=_("Result Content Type"),
    help_text=_("Content type of the result data"),
)
content_encoding = models.CharField(
    max_length=64,
    verbose_name=_("Result Encoding"),
    help_text=_("The encoding used to save the task result data"),
)
result = models.TextField(
    null=True, default=None, editable=False,
    verbose_name=_('Result Data'),
    help_text=_('The data returned by the task.  '
                'Use content_encoding and content_type fields to read.'))

def as_dict(self):
    return {
        'group_id': self.group_id,
        'result': self.result,
        'date_done': self.date_done,
    }

def __str__(self):
    return f'<Group: {self.group_id}>'

objects = managers.GroupResultManager()

class Meta:
    """Table information."""

    ordering = ['-date_done']

    verbose_name = _('group result')
    verbose_name_plural = _('group results')

    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['date_created']),
        models.Index(fields=['date_done']),
    ]
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for this new answer. The new constraint API is awesome. I’ve added a bit above your answer to answer the original question directly, so that I can except this as the new correct answer, because it’s much more relevant now.

Answer (score 39):

For anyone coming here wondering if they need an `index_together` in addition to `unique_together` to get the index's performance benefit, the answer for Postgres is [no](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Difference-between-UNIQUE-constraint-vs-index-td1877270.html), they are [functionally the same.](https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/uniqueness-in-postgresql-constraints-versus-indexes-4cf957a472fd)

Comment: Excellent addition, Tom. Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks for additional information! Tried to fix broken link, but cannot find working one. Can you, please, fix link or remove it at all?

Answer (score 14):

If `unique_together` does add an index, it will be a multiple column index.

If you want one of the columns to be indexed individually, I believe you need to specify `db_index=True` in the field definition.

Comment: I can confirm this from postgresql, here is an example from the postgresql console of a uniquere_toguether index: `public     | registration_something | registration_something_field_5c0b3bdb9d08b87c_uniq |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX registration_something_field_5c0b3bdb9d08b87c_uniq ON registration_something USING btree (field1, field2)`

Answer (score 7):

In **Django 1.5 and higher**, you can use the `{Model}.Meta.index_together` class attribute. If you had two fields named `foo` and `bar`, you would add:

```
class Meta(object):
    index_together = unique_together = [
        ['foo', 'bar']
    ]
```

If you have only one set of unique fields, you can use a one-dimensional iterable for `unique_together`. However, [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#index-together) does not indicate that the same applies to `index_together`.

This would also be okay:

```
class Meta(object):
    unique_together = 'foo', 'bar'
    index_together = [
        ['foo', 'bar']
    ]
```

This, however, is **NOT** supported by the documentation:

```
class Meta(object):
    unique_together = 'foo', 'bar'
    index_together = 'foo', 'bar'
```

Comment: `index_together` with 2 fields is different than `db_index=True` for the same 2 fields. `index_together` allows you to combine multiple indexes into 1, so that clauses like `WHERE a = 5 AND b = 10` can be compared while the database scans a single index.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together), it will only enforce uniqueness on database level. I think generally making a field unique does not imply it has an index. Though you could also simply check on db level if the index exists. Everything indicates though it does not.

Comment: The "imply" part of my question pertains to Django-specific behavior. `models.ForeignKey` sets `db_index=True` by default, in the field definition. I believe as well that a `unique=True` field also creates an index (database-level), which is how the unique checks operate quickly (correct me, if I'm wrong).

Comment: I think that depends how your database engine handles UNIQUE constraints. Most do set an index if I am right. This has nothing to do with Django though.

Comment: Indeed, the `models.ForeignKey` part has to do with Django, not the `unique=True`. I mentioned the `unique=True` as an aside, because of the `making a field unique does not...` portion of your answer.

Comment: `unique_together` is also enforced at the database level and not in Django. Assuming that your Database engine does support indexes on unique columns automatically, the index will be set. If not, then not. That's your answer. Additionally browsing through Django's code does not indicate they would set a db index on a `unique_together`.